# Firebase Database Reference for Retrieving Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I log in as a User B (**3wgmOhWlUUcyoBQXKZWnhw3K7Ik2**) and I want to retrieve location data of User A (**yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2**) from the database.

Here my database structure look like.

```
{
  "3wgmOhWlUUcyoBQXKZWnhw3K7Ik2" : {
      "name" : "MAMA",
      "type" : "P"
  },
  "yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2" : {
      "location" : {
          "latitude" : 3.0537728,
          "longitude" : 101.4826099
      },
      "name" : "AYAH NAN",
      "type" : "D"
  }
}
```

How can I write for the Firebase Database Ref to retrieve the location data? It is correctly this?

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2");
```

I should retrieve by ChildListener() or straight using getValue()?

Comment: To retrieve data you will always need to attach a listener. Since you're retrieving a single object, you should use a `ValueEventListener`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: The lat and long data is under location. How do i use ValueEventListener?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to read the latitude:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      double lat = dataSnapshot.child("location/latitude").getValue(Double.class);
    }
```

I highly recommend also reading the [Firebase Database documentation on reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) and then taking the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: I understand your guide sir. But after i read the documentation, I am confius about the last code that you wrote which is "...Double.class. I need to make another java class for the Double? Or it is because the **double** lat = ...

Comment: `Double` is an existing Java class. Calling `getValue(Double.class)` tells Firebase to retrieve the double value out of the snapshot, which is then stored in the `lat` variable.